# Unable to Load Model Trained in Gensim- pickle-related error

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, gensim

When attempting to load a word2vec model trained by Gensim on a Windows machine, I receive the following error:

`AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'EpochProgress' on <module '__main__'>`

I've successfully trained numerous models with Gensim in the past on this system. The only variation being this time I split the `model.build_vocab()` and `model.train()` phases, adding in saves & time hacks for each epoch. I also used a different iterator for the vocab build and the training phrases, but on the same dataset with the same tokenization pipeline.

Here is how I did the epoch progress tracking/saving:

```py
class EpochProgress(CallbackAny2Vec):
    '''saves the model after each epoch'''

    def __init__(self, path_prefix):
        self.path_prefix = path_prefix
        self.epoch = 0
        self.start_time = time.time()

    def on_epoch_begin(self, model):
        print("epoch #{} started".format(self.epoch))

    def on_epoch_end(self, model):
        print("epoch #{} completed".format(self.epoch))
        passed = (time.time() - self.start_time)/60/60 # elapsed time since start in HOURS
        print("{} hours have passed".format(str(passed)))
        output_path = get_tmpfile('{}_epoch{}.model'.format(self.path_prefix, self.epoch))
        model.save(output_path)
        print("model saved at: {}".format(output_path))
        self.epoch +=1
```

`epoch_progress = EpochProgress('E:/jade_prism/embeddings/phrase-embed-over- time/mega_WOS_word2vec/w2v_models/in_progress/')`

I then load the baseline model with the vocab build and set a few parameters:

```py
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load(baseline_models_directory+chosen_name)
model.window = window
model.size = size
model.workers = workers 
model.callbacks = [epoch_progress]
```

Then I do the training like this:

`model.train(corpus, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=epochs)`

And finally, save the end product like this:

`model.save('E:/w2v_models/trained/{}'.format(new_model_filename))`

Training appeared to work properly, and model saved as expected- unfortunately now I can't load it.

Here is the full Debug readout:

```
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> C:\anaconda\envs\mega_WOS\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py
> in load(cls, *args, **kwargs)    1329         try:
> -> 1330             model = super(Word2Vec, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)    1331 
> 
> C:\anaconda\envs\mega_WOS\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\base_any2vec.py
> in load(cls, *args, **kwargs)    1243         """
> -> 1244         model = super(BaseWordEmbeddingsModel, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)    1245         if not hasattr(model,
> 'ns_exponent'):
> 
> C:\anaconda\envs\mega_WOS\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\base_any2vec.py
> in load(cls, fname_or_handle, **kwargs)
>     602         """
> --> 603         return super(BaseAny2VecModel, cls).load(fname_or_handle, **kwargs)
>     604 
> 
> C:\anaconda\envs\mega_WOS\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py in
> load(cls, fname, mmap)
>     425 
> --> 426         obj = unpickle(fname)
>     427         obj._load_specials(fname, mmap, compress, subname)
> 
> C:\anaconda\envs\mega_WOS\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py in
> unpickle(fname)    1383         if sys.version_info > (3, 0):
> -> 1384             return _pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')    1385         else:
> 
> AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'EpochProgress' on <module
> '__main__'>
> 
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> 
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-4-0206f9f8f3ad> in <module>
>       3 
>       4 # Load the model based onthe model name
> ----> 5 model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load(model_name)
> 
> C:\anaconda\envs\mega_WOS\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py
> in load(cls, *args, **kwargs)    1339             logger.info('Model
> saved using code from earlier Gensim Version. Re-loading old model in
> a compatible way.')    1340             from
> gensim.models.deprecated.word2vec import load_old_word2vec
> -> 1341             return load_old_word2vec(*args, **kwargs)    1342     1343 
> 
> C:\anaconda\envs\mega_WOS\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\deprecated\word2vec.py
> in load_old_word2vec(*args, **kwargs)
>     170 
>     171 def load_old_word2vec(*args, **kwargs):
> --> 172     old_model = Word2Vec.load(*args, **kwargs)
>     173     vector_size = getattr(old_model, 'vector_size', old_model.layer1_size)
>     174     params = {
> 
> C:\anaconda\envs\mega_WOS\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\deprecated\word2vec.py
> in load(cls, *args, **kwargs)    1639     @classmethod    1640     def
> load(cls, *args, **kwargs):
> -> 1641         model = super(Word2Vec, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)    1642         # update older models    1643         if hasattr(model,
> 'table'):
> 
> C:\anaconda\envs\mega_WOS\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\deprecated\old_saveload.py
> in load(cls, fname, mmap)
>      85         compress, subname = SaveLoad._adapt_by_suffix(fname)
>      86 
> ---> 87         obj = unpickle(fname)
>      88         obj._load_specials(fname, mmap, compress, subname)
>      89         logger.info("loaded %s", fname)
> 
> C:\anaconda\envs\mega_WOS\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\deprecated\old_saveload.py
> in unpickle(fname)
>     377             b'gensim.models.wrappers.fasttext', b'gensim.models.deprecated.fasttext_wrapper')
>     378         if sys.version_info > (3, 0):
> --> 379             return _pickle.loads(file_bytes, encoding='latin1')
>     380         else:
>     381             return _pickle.loads(file_bytes)
> 
> AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'EpochProgress' on module '__main__'\>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python pickling/unpickling can run into problems when saving code blocks, or classes/instances-of-classes that you defined before saving, but may not be available at load-time. (Especially, anonymous or global-scope types not imported from explicit paths.)

It's a known hiccup with gensim model-saving, and future versions will likely avoid storing such callback code inside models at all. (Instead, you'll have to specify callbacks each time you execute a method using them, and they'll only remain effective for that one call.)

See [gensim project issue #2136](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2136) for more details, including a workaround that seems to have helped others re-load their models: ensuring the same `EpochProgress` class is defined/imported where the load is attempted.